# Python-vlc no funciona con pyinstaller

Tags: python

Cuando genero el `.exe` con ***pyinstaller***, no reproduce el vídeo con ***vlc***, ya puse las variables  de entorno en `path` de

> C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC

Pero el problema persiste, esto paso de un día para otro, ya que inicialmente si funcionaba bien.

Estoy utilizando **python 2.7**